# how to check if a variable is NaT in python?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, datetime, series, nat

I want to compare date value with NaT ,below is the value -

```
date_value = NaT

type(date_value) is <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>

if str(date_value) == ('NaT'):
    print("in if")
else:
    print("in else")
```

getting output as - in else , want to get 'in if' as the expected output.

Comment: in principle, try to provide [mre]s - `date_value = NaT` is invalid syntax: NaT is not defined

Comment: to check if a specific *element* of a pd.Series is NaT, you can use `isinstance(element, pandas._libs.tslibs.nattype.NaTType)` to be specific.

Answer (score 1):

Series is multiple values, so is possible test it there is at least one misisng value `NaT` by [`Series.isna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isna.html) and [`Series.any`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.any.html):

```
if date_value.isna().any():
    print("in if")
else:
    print("in else")
```